# Iterating over nested arrays in linear time

Tags: arrays, algorithm, big-o

The only way I know how to do this is by nesting loops. But this runs in O(n^2) time. My mentor told me that if ever, during an interview, I'm asked to solve a problem and I begin to do so by nesting loops, I should stop and rethink the problem. Apparently, there's always a better route than O(n^2). I've been thinking about this for a while, and I can't find an answer no matter how I rephrase my question on Google. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Apparently, there's always a better route than O(n^2)*

I believe this to be patently false. There are some problems that really are O(n^2). Unless there is a particular language feature to somehow make the problem more efficient, O(n^2) is the best you can for nested arrays.

Comment: Mmm... I agree almost completely except the "language feature" (unless the language feature is quantum computing). For certain problems quadratic time is the best algorithm we have.

Comment: @angelatlarge, I guess I was thinking along the lines of certain properties being cached for an array (such as count/length, sum, min, max, etc.). Certain operations could be conceivably sped up to O(n). Perhaps that's a stretch, though :)

Answer (score 2):

That is the fastest way to do it.

If you examine as many entries as there are entries in the total nested array structure... well, you clearly can't do better than that, can't you? ;)

Your confusion is that you think n = the dimension of the structure, but n actually = the number of entries in the structure total. So it is O(n) to use nested loops as long as the loops end as soon as there's nothing left at that level of nesting to examine